# OTRS 4.0 Error No config option found for the view 'Custom'

Tags: otrs, cmdb

I was using version 3.3 of the otrs and decided to upgrade to 4.0.9. I took to first uninstall all the modules that are not official (KIX4OTRS, complement and others), but after the upgrade by following the steps of the official documentation, without mistakes, I'm in trouble while trying to access the overview in the CMDB . The error occurs only in the overview, the creation and modification of items usually works.

Even after removing the KIX4OTRS still contained some messages it.

Error:
Backend ERROR: OTRS-CGI-10 Perl: 5.16.0 OS: linux Time: Wed Oct 21 14:26:45 2015 Message: No config option found for the view 'Custom'! RemoteAddress: 191.1.200.123 RequestURI: /otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentITSMConfigItem Traceback (3255): Module: Kernel::Output::HTML::LayoutITSMConfigItem::ITSMConfigItemListShow Line: 332 Module: Kernel::Modules::AgentITSMConfigItem::Run Line: 302 Module: Kernel::System::Web::InterfaceAgent::Run Line: 996 Module: ModPerl::ROOT::ModPerl::Registry::opt_otrs_bin_cgi_2dbin_index_2epl::handler Line: 41 Module: (eval) (v1.99) Line: 204 Module: ModPerl::RegistryCooker::run (v1.99) Line: 204 Module: ModPerl::RegistryCooker::default_handler (v1.99) Line: 170 Module: ModPerl::Registry::handler (v1.99) Line: 31

*I checked the Perl modules are all Okay
*My ITSM is version 4.0.9

Comment: Anybody? I still can not solve and need more tips. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It worked! Finally ... I used DataBase Browser software and deleted some entries and now I can access the CMDB. I deleted some entries referring to my ID in the table "user_preferences" session_id and session_profile. I'm not sure with was responsible for solving the problem.